# JQuery - delay and show text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, delay, settimeout

below i got some code, which should delay 2 seconds and hide previous span and show the next span, but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
  <style>
       span{ display:none}
 </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"><script>
<div id="text"></div>
<script>
    var text = [
        "<span>Sent A blabla</span>",
        "<span>sent B</span><span>sent b bbb cont....</span>",
        "<span>Sent c...</span><span>Sent C2</span><span>sent c3</span>", ];

    var text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
    jQuery('#text').html(text);
    jQuery('#text').show();
    jQuery('#text span:first').show();


  var delay = 2000;

  jQuery("#text span").each(function() {
      setTimeout( function(){ 
       var el = $(this);
        el.prev().hide();
        el.show();
      }, delay)
      delay += 2000;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well it is hard to loop through a list of spans when you only add one.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the javascript console? You may want to wrap this all in a $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: @neilsimp1 , nah code has no error in the console

Comment: @epascarello , yea i know wat u mean, but the span amount can be random, hence there could be 1 or even 10

Comment: You never add them to the DOM so you can not call prev or next since there is no siblings. The way you designed it, you need to add them all to the page to start.

Comment: Since you use three array keys but multiple SPAN elements... you've could  explain what's the desired output... nonetheless I've posted an example that actually don't cares about your funky array, it simply loops the SPAN elements.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, just having look at ur solution now :),  now my funky array are needed, we only need to work with one array item on page load / mouse click.

Comment: @TheDeveloper what does this mean? Can you please explain in details?? YOu have 3 arrays, but inside one array you have i.e: 2 SPAN elements. YOu know what I don't understand so please try to clarify

Comment: @TheDeveloper added some text at the bottom of my answer. Hopefully might help.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the help all sorted :)  used Sam Abushanab solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of your use of the keyword `this`.

Inside the for each statement you need to set a variable that is set to $(this) and then reference that variable in the timeout. Example below:

```
  var parent = $(this);
  setTimeout( function(){ 
   var el = parent;
    el.prev().hide();
    el.show();
  }, delay)
  delay += 2000;
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lykwmfz8/

Comment: `var el = parent;` why? Simply use `parent.prev()`... etc

Comment: I'm not referring to parent as a node in the DOM. Parent is a reference to the scope that its currently in. He is using the keyword in the wrong place.

Comment: I see now what you are referring to, but I simply copied what he had in his example. The issue isn't where he is calling element.prev(), the issue is his use of the keyword in the wrong scope.

Comment: I thought you'll get what I said. There's absolutely no reason to use a `var el` when you already can use your previously defined `parent`.

Comment: The way he has it causes no issues and is just a form of preference. It also has no bearing on why his code isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

It's all in the code comments:

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){ // FingerSaver: Use $ in the jQuery scope // It's also a DOM ready!

  var delay = 2000;       // You know this one :)
  var $text = $("#text"); // Cache your parent element

  // Elements Array.
  // You  have multiple SPANS per array key
  // (which is odd but OK... here's the array)
  var text = [
    "<span>Sent A blabla</span>",
    "<span>sent B</span><span>sent b bbb cont....</span>",
    "<span>Sent c...</span><span>Sent C2</span><span>sent c3</span>",
  ];

    // Append all SPANs to the #text parent:
    $text.html( text.join("") );
    // All SPANs are now inside #text but are hidden by CSS!

    // Get (cache) all appended SPANs
    var $spans = $text.find("span");

    // OK, how many SPANs we have?
    var tot = $spans.length;
    // (You had 3 array keys, but) 6 SPAN elements :)

    // Start c Counter with a random number
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * tot);

    // Create a function that will loop the texts
    (function loop() {
      c += 1;   // Increment counter
      c %= tot; // Reset counter back to 0 on reminder
      $spans.fadeOut(500).eq( c ).stop().fadeIn(500);
      setTimeout(loop, delay);
    }()); // Start!

});
```

```css
#text span{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
```

In the case you want to keep your collections of multiple SPAN elements and show as GROUPS than all you need to do is wrap every SPAN from an array key into a parent wrapper, and that do the same as above, just, instead of operating over SPANS you operate over their parents. Since you did not explained that well in your question the above is all I can give you so far.

Comment: can show and hide be used instead of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` ?

Comment: @TheDeveloper have you tried to simply, instead of `.fadeOut(500)` use `.hide()` and instead of `.fadeIn(500)` use `.show()`